# Datawarehouse and OLAP, ROLAP

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, olap

I have read all those article about datawarehouse and olap.....however I have some question on it

1. I have created a datawarehouse using mysql and I also created an API which contain ad-hoc query to query from the datawarehouse, so is this API consider as ROLAP?
2. Is it possible to create own OLAP? If yes, how?

Comment: Is it possible to create your own OLAP...of course... in the same way it is "possible" to create your own OS or RDBMS. As for if it will be cheaper than buying off the shelf...when is it ever cheaper? Heck when has MySQL (TCO) been cheaper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually data warehouse has normalized structure and DWH is not the same as ROLAP.

ROLAP it is technique used to modeling data. ROLAP is usually used for reporting. ROLAP is very good to make analytical query and you can use many reporting (BI) tools to easily build reports on you data.

It isn't necessary to write you own application to build reports. ROLAP (relational OLAP) it is when you model you data as "star" or "snowflake" using facts and dimension tables in traditional RDBMS. It star schemas also called "multidimensional cubes".

By OLAP often is meant MOLAP (multidimensional OLAP) - it's when you really store your data in multidimensional data structure in special data stores (not in RDBMS).

You shouldent create you own MOLAP e data storag- you should use alredy developed OLAP servers like MANDARIN, Pentaho Olap,Essbase, ORACLE EE database with OLAP option.

Comment: So how about my first question? so mean if my datawarehouse is star schema and multidimensional so it is consider as olap?

Comment: Yes, definitely, it is OLAP. OLAP systems have been traditionally categorized in three types: ROLAP,MOLAP,HOLAP.  And in your case it's  ROLAP.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion you are pointing out comes from the fact that peoples tend to use this term anywhere and in a wrong context.

OLAP applications are precisely defined by the OLAP council. These are applications that fullfill a bunch of requirements. You can read these requirements [Here](http://www.olapcouncil.org/research/whtpaply.htm).

In big words, these are analytical oriented applications that allow you to build reports in an a multidimensional fashion (it means you have dimensions and indicators that you can cross) and get fast anwsers at enterprise-scale, with drill down  and drill accross capabilities. Something close to OLAP applications is this : http://try.meteorite.bi/

Building an adhoc reporting engine on top of a datawarehouse doesn't mean you have an OLAP application. Does it have a multidimensional shape ? Is it user oriented ? Is it fast enough ? It has to answer yes to all these questions and the ones below to be a candidate to be an OLAP application.